# nginx rewrite rule not working

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all traffic to HTTPS, except two locations for domain validation.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    server_name xxxx.de www.xxxx.de;

    # SSLMate domain validation
    location /.well-known/pki-validation/ {
            proxy_pass https://xxxx.http-approval.sslmate.com$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            proxy_pass https://xxxx.http-approval.sslmate.com$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
    }

    # Redirect everything else to HTTPS
    location / {
            rewrite ^ https://xxxx.de/index.htm permanent;
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately everything is picked up by the rule for the "/" location. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a sample url that should be match by any of the first two location blocks, for example something like: xxxx.de/.well-known/pki-validation/ or xxxx.de/.well-known/pki-validation/something.html

Comment: How are you confirming that everything is `picked up by the rule for the "/" location`?

Comment: Does your `https` site set an HSTS header?